# Connect UserControl to a Datasource (ObjectDataSource in my case)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I'm trying to find a way to Databind a usercontrol to a datasource (an 
ObjectDataSource in my case) like in the case below :
`<uc1:AutoComplete ID="autoComCities" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="objCitiesDS" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" />`

I've try to find some good exemple with our lil' friend Google and I still 
ain't find anything concret. Someone can show me or give me good links on 
how I could do this. I mean, about how to handle it in my usercontrol ;o)

Thanks!

**Edit**
Note that in my case, it's not a Dropdownlist or any Bindable control in my usercontrol, its a normal asp.Net Textbox with some custom jQuery so when user type in the textbox, it shows "possibilities" under the textbox. So, I want to get values from the DataSrouce and put it into HTML so jQuery can Handles values and shows it to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use the ObjectDataSource, there is a lot of plumbing to get that to work.  You can pass the ID and call the Select() method to perform the selection manually and then get the values from the data and render them out.  You'll have to use reflection or DataBinder.GetPropertyValue method to extract the individual field values within each record.

HTH.

Comment: Could you provide me some examples to guide me? Considering all the "plumbing" as you said, would it be wiser to put a IDictionary<string, string> as property of my usercontrol, simply add values into it on OnInit of my page and then, bind it to my control into my usercontrol?

Comment: That would be more convenient yes, or add a Bind method that takes some data source.  It could be dictionary or could be a list too.  Data Source controls not using their existing plumbing are much harder to implement.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I'll go with my IDictionnary option. Because, it will be a "generic" Usercontrol so I don't realy know what will be in my IList. Playing with a IDictionnary insure me to have a Value and Key member at least.